# Glitch on method setOverlayImage Fabric.Js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

hey I am recently developing an application using fabric.js, and I found some glitch on `.setOverlayImage` method of `canvas`. U can see the glitch here at http://fabricjs.com/customization/ >> Overlay image section. If u look carefully on the image, there is a glitch when u make selection (by click and dragging to make selection). Its looks simple but when u doing it in big PNG this glitch really annoying. My question is, Can I remove or modifying anything to throw this glitch?

any help would be great :)